# PhantomJS can't read any tag in body on Nightwatch and Vue.js

Tags: selenium, webpack, phantomjs, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I'd like to UI test with Nightwatch for my Vue.js project.
I wanna use PhantomeJS for CI.

But PhantomeJS seems to read no element under body tag.
How do you assert any element with PhantomJS?

I caught this error:

```
√ Element <body> was visible after 47 milliseconds.
√ Testing if the page title equals "frontend".
× Testing if element <h2> contains text: "section 1". Element could not be located.  - expected "section 1" but got: "null"
```

My test source:

```
module.exports = {
  'toppage': browser => {
    browser
      .url(browser.launchUrl)
      // .assert.containsText('body', 'dummy')
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .assert.title('frontend')
      .assert.containsText('h2', 'section 1')
      .end()
  },
```

Then I confirmed body innerHTML was "".

```
Testing if element <body> contains text: "dummy".  - expected "dummy" but got: ""
```

nightwatch.config.js:

```
  desiredCapabilities: {
    // TODO chrome can cover these tests
    // browserName: 'chrome',
    // javascriptEnabled: true,
    // acceptSslCerts: true,
    // TODO but phantomJS can't
    browserName: 'phantomjs',
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    acceptSslCerts: true,
    'phantomjs.binary.path': 'node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/phantomjs.exe',
    'phantomjs.cli.args': ['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'],
  },
```

In case of Chrome, my test source run well.

versions:

nightwatch 0.9.20

webdriver-manager 12.0.6

selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar

phantomjs.exe 2.1.1

//////// added Mar.29 2018 ////////

I tried text.to.equal.

new test source:

```
  toppage: browser => {
    browser
      .url(browser.launchUrl)
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .expect.element('h2')
      .text.to.equal('section 1')
    // .assert.title('frontend') // TypeError: browser.url(...).expect.element(...).text.to.equal(...).assert.title is not a function
    // .containsText('h2', 'section 1') // TypeError: browser.url(...).expect.element(...).text.to.equal(...).containsText is not a function
    // .end() // TypeError: browser.url(...).waitForElementVisible(...).expect.element(...).text.to.equal(...).end is not a function
  },
```

new error message:

```
 √ Element <body> was visible after 46 milliseconds.
 × Expected element <h2> text to equal: "section 1" - element was not found  - expected "present" but got: "not present"
```

Answer (score 0):

While you invoke an url as `url(browser.launchUrl)` the *Web Client* requires a certain amount of time to render the *WebElements* within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). Hence you need to induce `wait` in the form of [expect-api](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/#expect-api) preferably an [expect-attribute](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/#expect-attribute) with respect to the attribute **.text** as follows :

```
browser.expect.element('#element_id').text.to.equal('dummy');
```

Next you can perform the *Assertion* as `assert.containsText('body', 'dummy')`

Comment: Thnx DebanjanB. It doesn't resolve it. I also add  .waitForElementVisible('h2', 60000) before .assert.containsText('h2'... It, too.

Comment: @isexxx `waitForElementVisible` won't suffice to your requirement. You need a waiter for the **text to be present**.

Comment: I get the message: Expected element <h2> text to equal: "section 1" - element was not found  - expected "present" but got: "not present" via browser.url(browser.launchUrl).expect.element('h2').text.to.equal('section 1') . browser.url(browser.launchUrl).expect.element('h2').to.be.present, too.

Comment: @isexxx Seems you are pretty closer now. can you update the question with your current code block & the error where you see the error and error log please?

Comment: I added new source and message. please refer to // added Mar.29 2018 //